# Seagate Backup Plus 5 TB became unresponsive after long period of use

Tags: macos, hard-drive, high-sierra, external-disk

I recently purchased a new Seagate Backup Plus 5TB for data use, because none of my drives are functioning properly. My old Seagate Expansion 2TB hard drive failed ("Unable to repair"); the Seagate Backup Plus 5TB that I borrowed became unresponsive after a period of use and has bad block (while writing it auto-rejects the drive); and the Seagate Backup Plus Desktop 5TB became unresponsive after a period of use.

After using the new drive for a while, I discovered that it will hang after 2-8 hours of continuous writing. By continuous, I mean literally all the time (downloading youtube videos and multiple torrents). I have read that hanging suggests bad block, and bad block suggests broken drive. What should I do? I've also heard that Seagate is not very reliable as to the quality of hard drives. Is it true?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Apple hardware, software or services in the [scope defined](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hmm - one computer and multiple drives. What's the chance your hub / cable / computer is the problem?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I'm using macOS and the filesystem is hfs+. All three previous drives are all formatted as hfs+ or apfs. I use the Apple USB C Digital AV multiport to connect to the drive. Does this information make this question more related to Apple?

Comment: @bmike I've run several Apple Hardware Test throughout this year and my computer has no hardware problems. I ran the test with my hub plugged in. I used the USB line that comes with each drive (so that is 4 different USB lines used now). Does that exclude the possibility of computer/cable fault?

Comment: @JoyJin Please consider [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/362761/edit) that information into the question.